Monotonicity of functions with undefined point?
Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $\left(a,b\right)$ and $f'$ is negative on $\left(a,b\right)$. Suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f\left(x\right)$ exists and denote it by $k$. For all $x\in \left(a,b\right)$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $a+\delta<x$ and $f\left(a+\delta\right)<k+\varepsilon$. By mean value theorem, we have $f\left(x\right)<f\left(a+\delta\right)<k+\varepsilon$. So $f\left(x\right)\leqslant k$. I was wondering whether this conclusion can be strengthened to $f\left(x\right)<k$.
